# Blitz++, armadillo and OpenMP very slow

Tags: openmp, armadillo, blitz++

I have been trying for very long time to learn how to parallelise and I have been reading lots of notes on OpenMP. So, I tried to used it and the results I get is that all placed where I tried to parallelise are 5 times slower than the serial case and I am wondering why...

My code is the next:

- `toevaluate` is a blitz matrix of two columns and rows length.
- `storecallj` and `storecallk` are just two blitz vectors that I used to store the calls and avoid extra function callings.
- `matrix` is an square armadillo matrix of length columns (cols= rows) and length of row is rows  (I will use it later for other thing and it is more convenient to define it as armadillo matrix)
- `externfunction1` is a function defined outside of this which computes the (x,y) values of f(a,b) function, where (a,b) is the input and (x,y) is the output.
- `Problem` is a string variable and `normal` is a boolean.
- `resultk` and `resultj` are such vectors (x,y) storing the output of such functions.
- `externfunction2` is another function defined outside of this which computes a double by evaluating funcci (i=1,2) which is a blitz polynomial. This polynomial gets evaluated in a double: innerprod to give another double: wvaluei (i=1,2).

I think these are all the generalities. The code is below.

```c
{
omp_set_dynamic(0);

OMP_NUM_THREADS=4;

omp_set_num_threads(OMP_NUM_THREADS);

int chunk = int(floor(cols/OMP_NUM_THREADS));

#pragma omp parallel shared(matrix,storecallj,toevaluate,resultj,cols,rows, storecallk,atzero,innerprod,wvalue1,wvalue2,funcc1, funcc2,storediff,checking,problem,normal,chunk) private(tid,j,k)
    {

        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (tid == 0)
        {
            printf("Initializing parallel process...\n");
        }
        #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule (dynamic, chunk) nowait
        for(j=0; j<cols; ++j)
        {
            for(k=0; k<rows; ++k)
            {
                    storecallj = toevaluate(j, All);
                    externfunction1(problem,normal,storecallj,resultj);
                storecallk = toevaluate(k, All);
                storediff = storecallj-storecallk;
                if(k==j){
                    Matrix(j,k)=-atzero*sum(resultj*resultj);
                }else{
                    innerprod =sqrt(sum(storediff* storediff));
                    checking=1.0-c* innerprod;
                    if(checking>0.0)
                    {
                        externfunction1(problem,normal, storecallk,resultk);
                        externfunction2(c, innerprod, funcc1, wvalue1);
                        externfunction2(c, innerprod, funcc2, wvalue2);
                        Matrix(j,k)=-wvalue2*sum(storediff*resultj)*sum(storediff*resultk)-wvalue1*sum(resultj*resultk);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is very slow. Another thing that I have tried is:

```c
for(j=0; j<cols; ++j)
{
    storecallj = toevaluate(j, All);
    externfunction1(problem,normal,storecallj,resultj);
   #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule (dynamic, chunk) nowait
    for(k=0; k<rows; ++k)
    {
        storecallk = toevaluate(k, All);
        storediff = storecallj-storecallk;
       ...
```

I am using dynamic because I am to avoid problems in case the total number of points to evaluate is not a multiple of 4.

Could someone please give me a hand to understand why this is so slow?

Comment: Sorry, in the second part I posted it does not include "collapse (2)" it is only

   for(j=0; j<cols; ++j)
    {
        storecallj = toevaluate(j, All);
        externfunction1(problem,normal,storecallj,resultj);
       #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic, chunk) nowait
        for(k=0; k<rows; ++k)
        {
            storecallk = toevaluate(k, All);
            storediff = storecallj-storecallk;
           ...

Comment: Reading the code, the very first thing to do (aside from checking which timer you use to measure this 5x result) would be to check the `private` vs. `shared` aspects of all variables. In first instance, you should consider that whichever scalar variable that is modified inside a parallel region shouldn't be `shared`. For example here, `storecallj` should be `private` I believe...

Comment: Thank you @Gilles, to mesure the time I use  timer.tic() and timer.toc() just outside the outer for region both in the parallelisation and in the serial version. 

storecallj is a vector, but you are right it is modified inside each thread. If I put it, along with all thread-modified quantities in privited I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)...  

If on the other hand, I keep all vectors:

storecallj,resultj,storecallk,storediff

as shared and privited all the doubles that changed in threads:

wvalue1,wvalue2,checking

the program run but still 5 times slower.

Comment: IDK what `timer.tic()` and `timer.toc()` do... For timing OpenMP codes, it is recommended to use `omp_get_wtime()`... Now for your various temporary variables that need to be set `private`, just declare them inside the `parallel` region instead of outside. This way, they will become implicitly `private`, which is what you want and which incidentally will make you code much more readable.

Comment: Thank you again @Gilles, I tried that:
#pragma omp parallel shared(variables)  private(tid,j,k)
{
omp_set_dynamic(0);
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4;
omp_set_num_threads(OMP_NUM_THREADS);

Array<double,1> resultj(2), resultk(2), storecallj(2), storecallk(2), storediff(2);

double innerprod,wvalue1, wvalue2, checking;

#pragma omp for schedule (dynamic, chunk) nowait
for(...j...)
{
    storecallj = toevaluate(j, All);
    externfunction1(problem,normal,storecallj,resultj);
    for(...k...)
    {
using omp_get_wtime() the time is still the same. It is hard for me to see why is slow...

Comment: The size of the evaluation is 39000 elements in row and 39000 elements in the columns.

Comment: Thank you @Gilles for the good advice of defining the variables inside the parallel section. That helped me a lot with another routine that was giving different results in parallel and serial. With that idea of defining the variables inside, that routine now gives the same results both in parallel and serial. However, all is 5 times slower. Could it be that is slower with Blitz++ vectors? I don't know much about it but Blitz++ manual says it was built to be run in serial and it could be ran un parallel by adding the flag: -DBZ_THREADSAFE which I do when compiling... Could that be the reason?